# Using twig|without for a commerce product

Tags: 8, commerce

I have a twig template for my commerce product, `commerc-product--contenttype.html.twig`:

```
<article{{ attributes }}>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      {{ product.field_price_original }}
      {{ product.variation_price }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      {{ product.field_discount_percentage }}
    </div>
  </div>
  {{ product|without('variation_attributes', 'product.field_price_original', 'product.variation_price', 'product.field_discount_percentage') }}
</article>
```

I want to print three fields separately first and then print the rest of the content except for the first three fields (which have already been printed).

However, [even though this note implies that without can take multiple values](http://www.webmaster-forums.net/html-css-and-javascript/how-hide-multiple-fields-display-drupal-8-using-twig-without-filter), everything is being printed; the `without` is ignored.

If I try a single value like this:

```
  {{ product|without('product.field_price_original') }}
```

The `without` is still ignored.  What might be the cause of this?

Drupal 8.4 and Commerce 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove the sub-keys below `product`:

```
article{{ attributes }}>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      {{ product.field_price_original }}
      {{ product.variation_price }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      {{ product.field_discount_percentage }}
    </div>
  </div>
  {{ product|without('field_price_original', 'variation_price', 'field_discount_percentage') }}
</article>
```